# How to encrypt a photo/file using triple DES ? ( which will be uploaded to drop box )

Tags: java, android, encryption

I wanted to know how to encrypt a file or a photo which will eventually uploaded into the dropbox.

As i have research online and only manage to found this code (pasted at the bottom) which only encrypt the password, but I wanted to know how to encrypt a file or a photo which will eventually uploaded into the dropbox instead.

So is there any reference or help or guide on how to write a java programming ( will be using on Eclipse software ) on encrypting a file using triple DES? Thank you so much.

```
package com.kushal.utils;

import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class DESEncryption {

private static final String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF8";
public static final String DES_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME = "DES";
private KeySpec myKeySpec;
private SecretKeyFactory mySecretKeyFactory;
private Cipher cipher;
byte[] keyAsBytes;
private String myEncryptionKey;
private String myEncryptionScheme;
SecretKey key;

public DESEncryption() throws Exception
{
    myEncryptionKey = "ThisIsSecretEncryptionKey";
    myEncryptionScheme = DES_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME;
    keyAsBytes = myEncryptionKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
    myKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(keyAsBytes);
    mySecretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
    key = mySecretKeyFactory.generateSecret(myKeySpec);
}

/**
 * Method To Encrypt The String
 */
public String encrypt(String unencryptedString) {
    String encryptedString = null;
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] plainText = unencryptedString.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
        byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
        BASE64Encoder base64encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        encryptedString = base64encoder.encode(encryptedText);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return encryptedString;
}
/**
 * Method To Decrypt An Ecrypted String
 */
public String decrypt(String encryptedString) {
    String decryptedText=null;
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        BASE64Decoder base64decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        byte[] encryptedText = base64decoder.decodeBuffer(encryptedString);
        byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(encryptedText);
        decryptedText= bytes2String(plainText);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return decryptedText;
}
/**
 * Returns String From An Array Of Bytes
 */
private static String bytes2String(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i &lt; bytes.length; i++) {
        stringBuffer.append((char) bytes[i]);
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}

/**
 * Testing the DES Encryption And Decryption Technique
 */
public static void main(String args []) throws Exception
{
    DESEncryption myEncryptor= new DESEncryption();

    String stringToEncrypt="Sanjaal.com";
    String encrypted=myEncryptor.encrypt(stringToEncrypt);
    String decrypted=myEncryptor.decrypt(encrypted);

    System.out.println("String To Encrypt: "+stringToEncrypt);
    System.out.println("Encrypted Value :" + encrypted);
    System.out.println("Decrypted Value :"+decrypted);

}   

}
```

Comment: Any good reason for using 3DES instead of a modern cipher like AES? And what are you using as key? A random number, or a user entered password? In the second case you need to apply key strengthening. I also strongly recommend using authenticated encryption in some form.

Comment: Authenticated encryption *may* not be needed if the photo is only uploaded to dropbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File reading is taken from [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/file2bytearray.html)

```
public static byte[] encryptFile(String pFilePath, byte[] pKey) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
{
    File file = new File(pFilePath);
    long length = file.length();
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

    // You cannot create an array using a long type.
    // It needs to be an int type.
    // Before converting to an int type, check
    // to ensure that file is not larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.
    if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        // File is too large
    }

    // Create the byte array to hold the data
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

    // Read in the bytes
    int offset = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    while (offset < bytes.length
           && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
        offset += numRead;
    }

    // Close the input stream and return bytes
    is.close();

    // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
    if (offset < bytes.length) {

        throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
    }

    SecretKeyFactory lDESedeKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
    SecretKey kA = lDESedeKeyFactory.generateSecret(new DESedeKeySpec(pKey));

    IvParameterSpec lIVSpec = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
    Cipher desedeCBCCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

    desedeCBCCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, kA, lIVSpec);
    byte[] encrypted = desedeCBCCipher.doFinal(bytes);

    return encrypted;
}
```

Comment: No random IV, and I don't know why you would want to convert a secret key to a secret key. Otherwise you *do* read in the file (there is a convenience method in Java 7 for that) and you correctly perform DESede encryption. The IV should be created by  secure random and prepended.

Comment: Corrected for the key thanks.
The IV initialization can be discussed depending on what is wanted. 

The alternative version with a secure random is as follow :
    `SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte bytes[] = new byte[8];
    random.nextBytes(bytes);
    IvParameterSpec lIVSpec = new IvParameterSpec(bytes);`

Comment: `SecretKeyFactory lDESedeKeyFactory =    SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
    SecretKey kA = lDESedeKeyFactory.generateSecret(new DESedeKeySpec(pKey));`
 what is the meaning of this?

Comment: It allows to create a key that can be used in the Cipher from a 24 byte long bytearray. If the byte array pKey isn't 24 byte long a GeneralSecurityException is raised by DESedeKeySpec. If you already have a SecretKey or a PublicKey use it directly

Comment: hmmm.. okay i roughly get what u mean.. But not fully.. Beginner here. anyway what is IV initialization ?  the first comment that u commented.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29

Answer (score 0):

A file can probably be read as a string of binary digits (lots of 1's and 0's). You could read the file, then encrypt the string using DES the same way you would a password, outputting the result to a new file.

Decryption would work the same way, reading the encrypted file, decrypting, and outputting to an unencrypted file.

Comment: Hmm how will i do by reading the file? As I am new to this, so I am not so sure.